# Use Python in powershell with conda environment activated

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I have a `conda` environment named `ml`, and I have activated this environment in `powershell` using following commands:

```sh
>> conda init powershell
>> conda activate ml
(ml) >>
```

When I open a notebook with `jupyter notebook` command, it works fine and I have access to the modules inside `ml` environment:

```py
import torch  # No errors inside a jupyter notebook cell
```

But when I try to test my modules inside the powershell and Python prompt, it doesn't work:

```sh
(ml) >> py
Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

I'm newbie to the conda environments. Is there any way to use conda environments within Python prompt of windows powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `pytorch` is installed in your environment using:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
```

Comment: It is not only about the pytorch. `import seaborn as sns` and `import pandas as pd` also cause error, while they're already installed in the environment.

Comment: @Tabaraei What's the output of `conda list` inside `m1`?

Comment: there are many, but I can assure you that pytorch, seaborn, and pandas are there.

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be some issue with the conda initialization in the powershell try restarting the powershell once you have done init

```
conda init powershell
```

and then activate environment then it should work

Comment: I have done restarting the powershell. and I did it again too with your solution, but it didn't work